# How to disallow only characters into input field using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need not to allow only characters to my input field and want to check the validation using Angular.js. My code is below.

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right oditek-form" style="width:180px">Longitude:</span>
<div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.longitude.$touched && billdata.longitude.$invalid }">
<input type="text" name="longitude" id="longitude" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="Add Longitude coordinate" ng-model="longitude"  ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/" ng-keypress="clearField('businessno');" >
</div>
<span class="input-group-btn">
<a ui-sref="dashboard.customer.view" class="btn btn-success" style="height:30px;" title="Click Here" ng-click="getLongValue();"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
 </span>
</div>
```

In the above code I have set also some regular expression into `ng-pattern` but its not allowing the number like `-12.345,+2.345 etc`. Here I need this field will only allow numbers('i.e-1,2...9'),special character like (`only +, -, . etc`).

Comment: My reg exp is really rusty but I would think something in the line of '([+-]([0-9]+([,.][0-9])*)*'

Comment: I'd think this regex is what you need `/[0-9,\.+-]/`

Comment: It is however allowing the characters to come in any order aren't they? Like for instance: ', 0+.-'

Answer (score 0):

This pattern for `ng-pattern` should match:

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9,\.\-\+]+$/"
```

Answer (score 0):

may be ng-pattern = "/[0-9,\W]/g"